# How to go back to the intent after answering Yes or No

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I made my skill that you can start a new game. Although, If a user has a game in session or wants to start a new game I have a session variable in place that `game_in_progress`. It says, `"There is a game in progress, would you like to contiune?"`

How can I map this back to another intent or check in the `Yes Intent` if its coming from some intent?

Heres what I have

```
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("AMAZON.StartOverIntent"))
def start_over_intent_handler(handler_input):
    # Check if game in play
    session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes

    game_in_progress = int(session_attr['game_in_progress'])

    if game_in_progress == 1:
        speech_text = f"""
                        You have a game in progress would you like to continue?
                       """
```

Keep in mind my YES Intent will be used later on for other stuff. How can I determine that I specially said YES from this intent to start a new game?

I looked it up online, some people set a state and then declare another YES intent with a `state != or == {YourState}` - I don't know if this works or even it's the correct way of doing it.

I am doing this in Python using decorators.

Answer (score 0):

`AMAZON.YesIntent` will be triggered whenever the user says *”yes”* and there might be other questions which can have “*yes”* as an answer. As a developer you have the control over what questions or response are being asked/given. Keeping a track of the questions/responses using `sessionAttributes` will help you to find out for what the user said “yes”.

Ex:   Use a session attribute “question_type”

```
Alexa: "There is a game in progress, would you like to continue?"  
[question_type = “continue_session”]
User: “yes”
```

Now when the `AMAZON.YesIntent` handler is triggered you can check the `question_type` `sessionAttribute`  to take appropriate action in your back end.

In short the answer is use `sessionAttirbutes` effectively to determine the context/state of the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Handling this with sessionattributes will make code clumsy as you will have to write all if else in yesnohandler.

Better is if you could use stack to keep track of handlers to be called.

When you ask a yes no question to a user, you put the handler class object onto the stack. Now when user responded with yesno, you pickup the handler object which is available on top of stack and call its proper method.

Comment: Thank you! Can you link me a document for Stacks? Im not sure what you mean, I am trying to find it myself.